# Invoking a function of library libfprint in Python using ctypes

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I need help to call a function(Struct C) that detects the devices, so I'm calling the function this way:

```
from ctypes import *
fp = CDLL('./libfprint.so.0')
fp.fp_discover_devs.argtypes = None
fp.fp_discover_devs.restype = c_char_p
ret = fp.fp_discover_devs()
print ret # is "0"
```

That is not detected any device, because the return is "0".

See the documentation of the function:

```
struct fp_dscv_dev\** fp_discover_devs (void) [read]

Returns:
a NULL-terminated list of discovered devices.
```

I'm using Ubuntu and I downloaded the "fprint_demo" and works perfectly. Did you install any package missing?

Thanks.

Comment: you tagged that as c++, is there any reason for it? since python can't interface c++ directly.